# How to freeze a complete row in Excel with JExcelApi?

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I'm generating xls files using JExcelApi. Now what I need is to lock the headers because I have more than 300 rows.

Whenever I scroll I need to have headers to be shown. Can anyone help me to solve this. I have explored many sites but I didn't get the solution for it.

```
OutputStream out = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
servletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(out, wbSettings);
workbook.createSheet("Employee Details", 0);
WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

WritableFont times11pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 11);
WritableCellFormat times = new WritableCellFormat(times11pt);
// times.setWrap(true);

times.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);

WritableCellFormat timesCenter = new WritableCellFormat(times11pt);
timesCenter.setWrap(true);
timesCenter.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
timesCenter.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);

WritableFont times11ptBold = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 11,
        WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE);
WritableCellFormat timesBold = new WritableCellFormat(times11ptBold);
timesBold.setBackground(Colour.YELLOW);
timesBold.setWrap(true);
timesBold.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
timesBold.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTRE);

WritableCellFormat timesBoldLeft = new WritableCellFormat(times11ptBold);
// timesBold.setBackground(Colour.YELLOW);
timesBoldLeft.setWrap(true);
timesBoldLeft.setAlignment(Alignment.LEFT);
timesBoldLeft.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTRE);

WritableFont times11ptTitle = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 14,
        WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE);
WritableCellFormat timesTitle = new WritableCellFormat(times11ptTitle);
// timesBold.setBackground(Colour.YELLOW);
timesTitle.setWrap(true);
timesTitle.setAlignment(Alignment.LEFT);
timesTitle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTRE);

int rows = 6;
int maxcolumn = 0;
int sno = 1;

// TITLE CELL
//excelSheet.mergeCells(0, 0, datesBetween.size() + 4, 1);
/*addCaption(excelSheet, 0, 0, companyName, timesTitle);*/

// get current date time with Date()
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
Date currDate = new Date();
String currentDate = "" + dateFormat.format(currDate);

// excelSheet.mergeCells(1, 2, 2, 2);
// excelSheet.mergeCells(0, 2, datesBetween.size()+4, 2);
addCaption(excelSheet, 2, 2, "Duration: " + from + " to " + to,
        timesBoldLeft);

// excelSheet.mergeCells(1, 3, 2, 3);
// excelSheet.mergeCells(0, 3, datesBetween.size()+4, 3);
addCaption(excelSheet, 2, 3, "Genrated On : " + currentDate,
        timesBoldLeft);

timesBold.setBackground(Colour.YELLOW);
timesBold.setWrap(true);
timesBold.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);

addCaption(excelSheet, 0, 5, "S.No.", timesBold);
addCaption(excelSheet, 1, 5, "Employee Name ", timesBold);  
addCaption(excelSheet, 2, 5, "Employee Address", timesBold);
addCaption(excelSheet, 3, 5, "Employee City", timesBold);

excelSheet.getSettings().setHorizontalFreeze(5);

workbook.write();
workbook.close();

out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to freeze rows or columns using setHorizontalFreeze(int row) or setVerticalFreeze(int col) in SheetSettings class.

refer: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_4_3/docs/jxl/SheetSettings.html

Comment: is there any example. I have seen the above link but i am not at clirity as i am new.. Just calling the setHorizontalFreeze(int row) is enough  >

Comment: its simple as calling the setHorizontalFreeze method with the row number. if you are looking for examples, google search gives me this: http://r4r.co.in/java/apis/jexcel/basic/tutorial/jexcel_basic_tutorials.php?qid=679

Comment: If we give the a row , the complete row is freezed right ?

Comment: But under that i have data of 50 lines.. when i scroll down i am unable to have a freezed header.. The headers are not visible when i scroll down

Comment: you need to provide your code to help you any further.

Comment: Is there any relation to the os using in systme.. I am using linux mint

Comment: which version of excel are you using?  jexcel supports excel version upto 2003.  I would suggest to use Apache POI which is actively maintained.

Comment: Its 2000 to 2014..version 4.2.8.2